# In which location I need to do build for PhoneWindowManager.java changes in Android M

Tags: android

I am modifying the PhoneWindowManager.java for customizing the Navigation Bar in Android 6.0 for AOSP code. My Path to java file:

> ./frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/policy/PhoneWindowManager.java

The Android.mk is available in **/frameworks/base/services/core** and **frameworks/base/services** also.

So here is my query: 
Should I need to do build in :  **mmm frameworks/base/services -B** or where ?
Am I doing any mistake? please confirm. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build `mmm frameworks/base/services`.The Android.mk has something like this and */core* is built as part of this:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
13        core/java/com/android/server/EventLogTags.logtags
14
15# Uncomment to enable output of certain warnings (deprecated, unchecked)
16# LOCAL_JAVACFLAGS := -Xlint
17
18# Services that will be built as part of services.jar
19# These should map to directory names relative to this
20# Android.mk.
21services := \
22    core \
23    accessibility \
24    appwidget \
25    backup \
26    devicepolicy \
27    midi \
28    net \
29    print \
30    restrictions \
31    usage \
32    usb \
33    voiceinteraction
```

Are you seeing any issue when you build at this location.

Comment: Thanks Rupesh. Its building fine . So which one will give the correct binary and what is that binary. Is it service.jar?

Comment: Got the solutions. Its working after replacing the service.jar. Thanks.

Comment: @Subrat cool..in the older devices you will need remove odex files too to see the changes.